# Video games running in VMware are running slow while in the host machine are running fine

Tags: video, graphics-card, virtual-machine, vmware, lag

I play a game called Mu Online and it's very common to run multiple instances of this game in one single PC with virtual machines. In my case I have 3 VMs of VMware Player 12 running Windows XP and each of them only the game and a bot are running.

What I noticed is that the game is running very slow inside the VMs. It's not a "killer lag", but it's a substancial one. I would imagine that is my video card struggling to process 3 games at once, but after opening a 4th Mu client, this time in the host OS, I find it running 100% clean as when there is no VM with Mu open!

The impression I get is that the VMs are using not the video card (a NVidia GeForce GTX 560 Tti 448) for processing the video game, but the main processor (a Intel Core i5 2500K) instead. This is the only explanation I could guess for why any of the 3 MUs would be running slow inside the VMs but running clean in the host OS.

Assuming my explanation is correct, what could I do to tell VMWare Player I want the video card, not the processor running the video calculations? And if it's not this, what, then, it is and what should I do to solve this problem?

BTW I've already red articles on the web on how to increase the performance of VMs, but as it seems, the "common solutions" weren't enough.

Comment: I assume you have installed the VMWare extensions and installed the Nvidia drivers on the VM?

Comment: gpu passthrough is the technology you need for the virtual machine to use the raw graphics hardware.  intel calls it `VT-d` (Directed I/O).  you would need a cpu and a motherboard that supported it, and 1 gfx card for each VM you wanted to use it.  your 2500k provides `VT-x` but not `VT-d`, so that's out.  note if you use VT-d to give a VM your gfx card, the host will be locked out of it, so you'll need another to run stuff on the host as well.

Comment: @quixotic in other words, insofar my PC remains the same, I'll have to accept this poor performance, right? Well I guess that's more an answer then a comment, so please rewrite it as so so I may accept it as right answer.

Comment: @Ramhound actually I didn't, but given what quixotic mentioned in his comment, that would be useless, right?